# Choosing multiple items from a list in AppleScript

Tags: list, applescript

I need a choose from list dialog, whose result shows me another choose from list dialog and returns the result. I cannot figure out why the code below does not show the second choose from list dialog.

```
set hi to choose from list {"oh, hey", "sup", "bye"}
if hi = item 1 then
    set hey to choose from list {"how are you?", "no time for sall talk"}
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set hi to choose from list {"oh, hey", "sup", "bye"}

if hi = {"oh, hey"} then
    set hey to choose from list {"how are you?", "no time for sall talk"}
end if
```